# How to notify mainthread when completing WorkEvent with exception?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-8, workmanagers, commonj

I'm working with the [IBM WorkManager (v8.0.0)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/asynchbeans/WorkManager.html) to do some work asynchronous to the main thread.

For this I use the following code:

```
// wm = via resource injected WorkManager

WorkItem item = wm.startWork(work, WorkManager.INDEFINITE, new WorkListener() {

  @Override
  public void workStarted(WorkEvent arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void workRejected(WorkEvent arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void workCompleted(WorkEvent arg0) {
    WorkException exception = arg0.getException();
    if (null != exception) {
      throw new RuntimeException("WorkCompleted with Exception");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void workAccepted(WorkEvent arg0) {
  }
});
```

This works quite fine as long the `WorkEvent` was completed without an exception. But when it was completed with an exception, I want to notify the mainthread to stop it submitting more WorkItems to the `WorkManager`.

I thought I could raise an `RunetimeException` to notify the mainthread, but analysing the logs I found out that the exception is thrown in that moment the mainthreads finished submitting all `WorkItems` to the `WorkManager` and calling the `join`-method of the `WorkManager` - which is far too late (in most cases 50.000 items have to be done by the `WorkManager`).

So how can I interrupt my mainthread to stop it submitting more items to the `WorkManager` in this moment when an exception is recognized in `workCompleted`?

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "more direct" interface then.

Meaning; you are showing code that calls:

```
WorkItem item = wm.startWork(work, WorkManager.INDEFINITE, new WorkListener()
```

The class that contains that instructions need some "input" channel; for example there could be a "simple" field in that class `List<Exception>` that your work items **add** their exceptions to.

And your "main" class that creates those work items should check that list regularly; and simply stop adding new work items when an exception is found.

Of course, you have to make that thread safe, and provide a reasonable architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have implemented such a "bridge" and will test it later.